# Trying to implement Kendo UI angular 2 Grid Selector Error

Tags: angular, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-angular2

I am trying to create a demo application using Kendo, which I was able to do using Kendo UI. Now I got a requirement to try the same using Angular 2 Kendo UI. However I was stuck by following error.

My component code goes like this. Same as in sample code from the Kendo UI.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
        <kendo-grid [data]="gridData">
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductID" title="Product ID" width="120">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="ProductName" title="Product Name">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="UnitPrice" title="Unit Price" width="230">
            </kendo-grid-column>
            <kendo-grid-column field="Discontinued" width="120">
                <template kendoCellTemplate let-dataItem>
                    <input type="checkbox" [checked]="dataItem.Discontinued" disabled/>
                </template>
            </kendo-grid-column>
        </kendo-grid>
    `
})
export class GridComponent {

    private gridData: any[] = [{
        "ProductID": 1,
        "ProductName": "Chai",
        "UnitPrice": 18.0000,
        "Discontinued": true
    }, {
        "ProductID": 2,
        "ProductName": "Chang",
        "UnitPrice": 19.0000,
        "Discontinued": false
    }, {
        "ProductID": 3,
        "ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup",
        "UnitPrice": 10.0000,
        "Discontinued": false
    }, {
        "ProductID": 4,
        "ProductName": "Chef Anton's Cajun Seasoning",
        "UnitPrice": 22.0000,
        "Discontinued": false
    }, {
        "ProductID": 5,
        "ProductName": "Chef Anton's Gumbo Mix",
        "UnitPrice": 21.3500,
        "Discontinued": false
    }, {
        "ProductID": 6,
        "ProductName": "Grandma's Boysenberry Spread",
        "UnitPrice": 25.0000,
        "Discontinued": false
    }];
}
```

I have a common module class with following details

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }  from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { BookDetailComponent } from './distribution-detail/distribution-detail.component';
import { GridComponent } from './detail-grid/detail-grid.component';
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';


@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        SharedModule,
        HttpModule,
        GridModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        BookDetailComponent,
        GridComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DistributionService
    ]
})

export class DistributionModule { }
```

And the Grid Module selector is used in BookDetailComponent HTML code,

```
<my-app>Loading</my-app>
```

However I get the error

core.umd.js:2837 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
'grid-demo' is not a known element:
1. If 'my-app' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

Comment: Can you post the index.html and any other relative code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `DistributionModule` is your common module. And you import this module into your `AppModule`, then you should add the `GridComponent` and the `BookDetailComponent` to the export array of your `DistributionModule`:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule,
        SharedModule,
        HttpModule,
        GridModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        BookDetailComponent,
        GridComponent
    ],
    exports : [
       BookDetailComponent,
       GridComponent
    ],
    providers: [
        DistributionService
    ]
})
```

This way you can actually use the components defined inside your `DistributionModule`